# Update and Add a clickable link in the PDF generated using simple-headless-chrome npm

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-headless

I am using a `'simple-headless-chrome'` package of version `4.3.10` and using `"printToPDF"` to create a `PDF`.

I want to update/add the anchor tag in my `PDF` generated.

Is it possible to edit the link and/or update the text in the PDF runtime? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got the issue, make the element a link on the page and the `printToPDF` should take it as a link in the PDF.

Comment: Got another issue with the URL, if the url contains hash '#' in it, it isn't rendering in the PDF correctly.